# What was the origin and purpose of the "Montes"?

Tags: early-modern, papacy

Reading [*History of the Popes*, by von Ranke](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12001300-the-history-of-the-popes-their-church-and-state-and-especially-of-thei), the author mentions the creations of several **Montes** (one of them is Monte Pío). Does anyone know what is the date of the first Monte ever created and what were their purposes?

---

**EDIT:**

A translation of the the text of [The History of the Popes: Their Church and State](https://archive.org/stream/a605673803rankuoft#page/n7/mode/2up) by Leopold von Ranke is also available on Archive.org.

Comment: Can you include some more relevant information from the book, perhaps a quote, the years, which pope, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that 1472 would be the oldest, and they appear to be a form of a charity/bank/fund for the poor. According to this [site](https://www.gruppomps.it/en/about-us/history.html):

> Monte dei Paschi di Siena, the oldest bank in the world, originated in
>   1472 as a Monte Pio (pawn agency) at the behest of the Magistracies of
>   the Republic of Siena and was expressly instituted to give aid to the
>   more underprivileged classes of the population during a time of
>   particular hardship for the local economy.

If you are a Spanish speaker, [this site](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_P%C3%ADo_(beneficencia)) may give you some more info.
The [translated page](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=es&u=https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_P%25C3%25ADo_(beneficencia)&prev=search) is not very helpful.